# Jquery trigger with call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have button with onclick :

```
 <button   class="tablinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'default')">{'TEXT_DEFAULT_SETTINGS'|tr}</button>
```

openDiv function:

```
function openDiv(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

How can I trigger this onclick?

Comment: `document.querySelector(validSelctor).click()`

Comment: Its will work if you have element with id that passed you  `cityName`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[0].click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code working fine unless you dont have element with `default` as id. 
Else your code ll break & give error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` for this statement `document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";`

See the below working example of your code:

```js
function openDiv(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
#default {
display:none
}
```

```html
 <button   class="tablinks" onclick="openDiv(event, 'default')">{'TEXT_DEFAULT_SETTINGS'|tr}</button>

<div id="default">
This is a default div
</div>
```